# SQL Query help - Not sure how to do this without an ambigous outer join

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

In Access I have five related tables that I'm trying to get information from, but I'm not sure how to write this query. I'm not even really sure how to start. I have:

```
tblEmployee  tblCourseCatelog  tblSessions   tblInstructorDeliverables    
-----------  ----------------  -----------   -------------------------
EmpID (PK)   CatelogID (PK)    SessionID(pk) ID (PK) 
Name         CourseName        CatelogID     EmpID 
                               DateAndTime   CatelogID 

tblInstructorSessions
---------------------
ID (pk)
Instructor (fk tblInstructorDeliverables.ID)
SessionID
```

`tblEmployees` is a list of all employees. `tblCourseCatelog` is a table of all courses that are offered. `tblSessions` is a list of courses that have been scheduled. `tblInstructorDeliverables` is a table of employees who can instruct and what course they can instruct. `tblInstructorSessions` is a table of sessions that instructors have been assigned to instruct.

I'm trying to make a listbox on a form that will be populated with the name of instructors who are eligible to teach a certain course.

The trick is that I'm passing `SessionID` to the form, not `CatelogID`. The reason I'm doing this is to that I can assign the instructors to that session, so I will need that number.

e.g. A session had been setup. It is `SessionID` 1805. It is a first aid course (`CatelogID` 7). `frmAssignInstructors.OpenAgs = 1805`.

I want to now select and display in the listbox all instructors that can instruct CatelogID 7 by figuring out that SessionID 1805 is a first aid course.

I've only had one coffee today and I can use some help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form frmAssignInstructors OnLoad event code:

```
' Execute query, retrieve CatelogID
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT SessionID, CatelogID FROM tblSessions WHERE SessionID = " _
     & Me.OpenArgs & ";"

' Form has a Control txtCatelogID whose ControlSource is CatelogID
Me.ListBox.RowSource = "SELECT ID, EmpID, CatelogID FROM " _       
    & "tblInstructorDeliverables WHERE CatelogID = " & txtCatelogID.Value & ";"
```

This way, you first load the Sessions data into the form RecordSource, then construct the ListBox RowSource from the retrieved CatelogID value.

Comment: That works. Way easier than what I was trying to do. Plus, after I had more coffee, I was able to read what you wrote!!!

Answer (score 0):

There's more an issue of database modelling that on implementation.

You could create a table relating tblCourseCatAlog and tblInstructorDeliverables, let's call it instructor_x_course, because it is a N x N relation and because in my point of view this information should not be provided by the Session entity. You can create this table with the following columns: CatalogID (FK) and instructorID (FK). This table will contain information of which instructor is able to teach what course and vice-versa.

After that, it is going to be easy to filter classes that can be given by a certain instructor. Create a query using this new table and instructor's one, in order to bring instructor details. Use the Access wizard for the listbox control to source your listbox to this query.

There's quicker ways to solve your problem as it is, but experience shows that "patches" are expensive in maitenance.

Finally, consider your information flow, because it seems a bit confusing. You are giving instructor parameters to a form that will bring information of more instructors that are able to teach the same course? If it is the point, ok, but try to keep your application robust and minimalist. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have mentioned that! One session may have many instructors. It gets kind of busy around here!